# Can't hear the sound in python from winsound

Tags: python

```
import winsound
winsound.PlaySound("rickroll",winsound.SND_FILENAME)
```

It doesn't give error but i cant hear the sound can you guys help me with it ?

Comment: Does your file have an extension name?

Comment: no its the same

Comment: Is it in wav format?

Comment: no it isnt its mp3

Comment: It won't work for anything that's not wav. Either export it using Audacity or something similar or use a different library that can handle it.